# How to stream video directly recorded by iPhone camera?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, video-capture, live-streaming

I have one requirement for capturing the video and broadcast it while shooting the video.

I searched many things and found 4 steps but i don't have any suggestion for first initial steps of how to capture video and broadcast it while shooting.

I have found below steps but there is no any explanation for capturing and broadcasting video.

1. You can use "Wowza media Server" for Streaming purpose For wowza
   media server doenload :
2. After installing wowza Now you need to set up live setting in wowza
   for that purpose you need:
3. RTMP library for Streaming

So can anyone please make me understand below questions:

1. How to record video ?
2. How to broadcast video while shooting ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be more specific http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios

Comment: stackoverflow is not your personal research assistant, please post what you have tried to solve this issue yourself. Just posting your requirements and expecting a solution is frowned up and might get your question voted down. Please post any steps you have done to slave this issue your self.

Comment: @rckoenes: I have recorded the video but i cant get clue for how to send every frame to server while recording. I also have installed wowza server but how to send part of video to server that i don't know. I just asked on stack overflow because i know that stackoverflow is very big knowledge sharing center. I appreciate your suggestion. Thank you very much.